# AngularJS Directives - prioritize child over parent

Tags: angularjs

How do I prioritize a child to compile before a parent?

For instance, say I have a directive that compiles Markdown, and I want to keep the markdown file separate.  So I could:

```
<div markdown>
    <ng-include src='"someMarkdownFile.md"'></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can not figure out how to get ng-include to compile first.

I've tried putting them on the same element and set the `markdown` directive to `terminal`, eg:

```
<div markdown ng-include src='"someMarkdownFile.md"'></div>
```

but since ng-include is terminal, it is never run before the markdown directive.

Is this possible?

**ANSWER**

Looks like the answer is, you can't.  Brandon's answer helps with my particular case but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in Angular.

To expound upon Brandon's answer below, I changed my HTML to this:

```
<div markdown src='someMarkdownFile.md'></div>
```

And had the directive check the `src` attribute.  If it exists, run:

```
    $http.get(src, {cache: $templateCache}).success(function(resp) {
      return element.html(resp);
    }).error(function() {
      throw new Error("Could not load " + src + " from markdown directive");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could tackle this.

First, `ngInclude` [emits an event](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude#$includeContentLoaded) every time its content is reloaded:

> #### `$includeContentLoaded`
>
> Emitted every time the ngInclude content is reloaded.
>
> **Type:**
> emit
>
> **Target:**
> the current ngInclude scope

So, your `markdown` directive could watch for this event and recompile the markdown:

```
app.directive('markdown', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      // ...
      scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
        recompileMarkdown();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Another option, of course, is not not use `ngInclude` at all, and have your `markdown` directive fetch its own markdown files perhaps even using `$templateCache` or some other `$cacheFactory` cache for caching. (This is probably the direction I'd go; even if you get `ngInclude` to work, there's still a DOM element sitting in your markdown--controlling the content yourself, I believe, would be easier in the long run.)

Comment: Don't believe so; from the docs (emphasis mine): "When there are multiple directives **defined on a single DOM element**, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied." It doesn't affect parent/child relationships, and since `ngInclude` is terminal, as mentioned in the question, you can't put the directives on the same element.

Comment: Great answer, thanks Brandon.  I agree, 2nd option is probably a bit cleaner.  I'll give it a shot and will update.